# Getting events to work in cakephp 3.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I am trying to get the events functionality of cakephp to work in cakephp 3.4 and its taking me centuries to figure it out. Will appreciate all the help I can get.
I want verification email to be sent to users after saving their information.
In the users controller >>register method

```
public function register()
    {
       // $this->viewBuilder()->getLayout('logo-only');
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if($this->Users->processRegistration($user)) {

            }else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Your account was not created, check highlighted form fields to correct errors'));
            }
        }        
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }
```

In my UserTable

```
public function initialize()
{
   parent::intialize();
   $event = new UserListener();
   $this->eventManager()->on($event);
}

public function processRegistration ($entity)
    {
        if ($this->save($entity)) {
            $event = new Event('Model.Users.afterRegister', $this, ['user' => $entity]);
        $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
        return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In my src/Event/UserListener.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Event;

use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

class UserListener implements EventListenerInterface {

    public function implementedEvents () {
        return [
            'Model.User.afterRegister' => 'afterRegister'
        ];
    }

    public function afterRegister ($event, $user)
    {
        $email = new Email('default');
        $email->setFrom(['support@example.com' => 'Example Site'])
            ->setTo('admin@example.com')
            ->setSubject('New User Registration - ' . $user['username'])
            ->send('User has registered in your application');
    }
}
?>
```

Hope I was able to make sense to a point assistance can be offered. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Now working fine;
My implemented 'Model.User.afterRegister' in my listener but was busy calling 'Model.Users.afterRegister' in my UserTable.
Hope you also learnt something from this #smilinWithEyesCovered